# Utilizing comparison function fails with reference types

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a templated class which looks as follows (assume a `using namespace std` for brevity):

```
template <typename Type, typename Compare = less<Type>>
struct weighted_base
{
    typedef typename set<pair<Type, double>, set_compare<Type, Compare>> mapped_type;
    map<Type, mapped_type, Compare> backing_map;
    ...
};
```

where `set_compare` is defined as:

```
template <typename Type, typename Compare>
struct set_compare
{
     bool operator()(const pair<Type, double>& a, 
                     const pair<Type, double>& b)
     {
         return Compare(a.first, b.first);
     }
};
```

That is, the map takes keys of type `Type` to `std::set<std::pair<Type, double>>` values. This has some problems when I use a method such as:

```
void insert(const Type& from, const Type& to, double weight)
{
    //...
    mapped_type& adj_nodes = backing_map[from];
    adj_nodes.insert(make_pair(to, weight));
}
```

The problem is that within the `set`, when it goes to call `set_compare`, it has a type of `const Type&`, not `Type`. Thus, assuming it's `std::less`, in this case it will be trying to call `less<int>::less(const int& a, const int& b)` which fails.

Is there some way of fixing it so that both contains can use (effectively) the same comparison function here?

Comment: Reading your code and trying to understand what is going on gives me a headache. Maybe you should elaborate more on the sentence: "The problem is that within the set, when it goes to call set_compare, it has a type of const Type&, not Type."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Compare` is the type of a binary functor, so you probably need

```
return Compare()(a.first, b.first);
```

where `Compare()` is a temporary, defualt constructed,  `Compare` instance. For example, if you substitute `Compare` for `std::less<int>`,

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << std::less<int>(5,50) << "\n"; // Error!
std::cout << std::less<int>()(5,50) << "\n"; // OK
```

Your error is likely to give you many compiler errors, some of which could send you down the wrong track. I suggest fixing it first, then seeing if the code behaves as you expect it to.